# With CSS and HTML how do I achieve my output this way

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write some HTML that looks like this:

[image: my want]

But what I currently have looks like this:

[image: My currently output]

This my code:

```html
<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
left: 32px;
text-align: center;
} 

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div class='relative'>phone <b> 07010710811</b>
  shot code <div class='absolute'> <b>123456 </b></div>
</div>";
```

What should I do to get my desired output?

Comment: try to add  `line-height: 40px;` in the absolute div

Comment: Okay let me give a try

Comment: Same output I just tried

Comment: What can you modify? The HTML, CSS or both?

Comment: I've created an answer, but it is assuming you have freedom to modify the HTML. Let me know if it helps, or if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another `div` for your "shot code", and "phone" text. I've used similar properties to what you have been using before so that it should fall in line with the rest of your styling.

I would also consider renaming your `div`'s to something that isn't a CSS property.

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  left: 32px;
  text-align: center;
} 

div.shot_code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: -2px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  text-align: center;
}

div.shot_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.phone_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='phone_text'>phone</div> <b> 07010710811</b>
  <div class='shot_text'>shot code</div>
  <div class='shot_code'> <b>123456 </b></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can modify the HTML I would restructure it somewhat. That will make your life a lot easier when it comes to getting this styled right, and also styling it in the future.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
left: 32px;
} 

.phone-num{
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.shot-code-num {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.shot-code{
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='phone'>phone 
       <span class="phone-num">07010710811</span>
  </div>

  <div class="shot-code">
     shot code
     <div class='shot-code-num'> <b>123456 </b></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can quite possibly also remove the absolute positioning as well, and replace it all with inline-blocks. It looks like you are going for something more like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  text-align:right;
} 

.field{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
}
.field-label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:70px;
  text-align:left;
  padding:10px;
}

.field-value {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="phone field">
       <span class="phone-label field-label">phone</span>
       <span class="phone-value field-value">07010710811</span>
  </div>

  <div class="shot-code field">
     <span class="shot-code-label field-label">shot code</span>
     <span class="shot-code-value field-value">123456</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure what other requirements you have, so can't say for sure. You have a few options here. Hope some of it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) and `with` properties, like that :

```css
.box{
  float :left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  
}
.top{
  width: 100%;
}
.cut{
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.border{
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="top">
    Phone 07010710811
  </div>
  <div class="cut">
    shot code
  </div>
  <div class="cut border">
    123456
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you have to adapt this code to your case.